# How can I get the domain names from a list of IP addresses

Tags: dns, ip

I have a text file with a list of IP addresses and I'd like to be able to match those with their respective domains.  Is that possible to do somewhat easily and if so, can someone point me in the correct direction on how to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

(Since you've not mentioned any language ..i'm assuming that you're going to use .Net)

Use

```
System.Net.Dns.Resolve();
```

you can pass in IP address and get the resolved hostname.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are satisfied with seeing whether there is a reverse DNS mapping,

```
 xargs -n 1 host <ips.txt
```

If you want the names of all the hosts whose forward DNS resolves to this particular IP address, that's significantly more challenging, but probably also more useful (reverse DNS is neglected by some ISPs, and when it does exist, it often doesn't help answer any useful question you might have). There is no straightforward and quick technique for this, but DomainTools and their competitors have painstakingly distilled databases through crawling which they will be happy to accept your money for.